# Clear example of Service module authentication and authorization

Tags: 7, users, services

I've been playing around with [Service module](http://drupal.org/project/services), which it seem the best module for exposing web service specificaly I have REST architecture. Nevertheless haven't been able to clear how does the authentication and authorization works here.

I know than I can expose a specific method like this:

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_service()
 */
function custom_service_services_resources() {
...

 return array(
    'volunteer'=>array(
    'actions'=>  'disable'=>array(
        'callback'=> '_custom_service_disable',
        'file' => array('type' => 'inc', 'module' => 'custom_service', 'name' => 'inc/custom_service'),
        'args'=> array(
            array(
                'name' => 'id_entity',
                'type' => 'string',
                'description' => 'The ID of the record',
                'source' => 'data',
                'optional' => FALSE,
              )
        ),
      'help' => t('Service custom for example.'),
    ) ),
```

);
    }

And it work quite nicely but only with the admin user, I understand there are some extra access parameters like:

```
'access callback' => '_custom_service_access',
'access arguments' => array('disable'),
'access arguments append' => TRUE,
```

But they are not well documented, does anybody has an insight on how to use them in service module, thanks.

**Aditional Information**

Drupal Version: 7

[Service Module](http://drupal.org/project/services)

**Edit**

Apreciate the answer but the hook about the auth can be found in

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-drupal-web-service-project/index.html

The problem with this example are:

- The service access function (_note_service_access) will always return TRUE. That means that all calls are authenticated.
- Why do they do

  $access = user_access('note service delete any note');
  $access = $access || $note->uid == $user->uid &&

If they are not going to use it.

One last fact If I don't use the admin user with the services I can't get authorization.

Comment: What version of Drupal and services module are you using ?

Comment: Using the latest version of the module and drupal 7